# Gitlab Runner waiting before launching next pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

My Gitlab Runner sometimes wait for a few minutes (up to 10mn) to start a new pipeline, even if all runners are free.

Is it normal ? Is there an option I missed ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

During our testings, we created a lot of runners that were unused.

After removing these from our Gitlab, then cleaning gitlab-runner by deleting inactive runners one by one, our pipelines are now starting without delay :)